# How to mock activity in test class or getApplicationContext

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I have an Android unit test class where I need to use Activity or Context.

How can I mock it?

I tried this but it did not not work:

```java
this.mActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(CheckoutLocationActivity.class);
```

Error trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowImpl.extract(ShadowImpl.java:14)
        at org.robolectric.shadow.api.Shadow.extract(Shadow.java:25)
        at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:30)
        at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:22)
        at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.<init>(ActivityController.java:65)
        at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:56)
        at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:89)
        at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:75)
        at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:102)
```